# Recursion function in two types for Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

This is the original code for Fibonacci sequence by using Recursion

```
def rec(n):
if n<=1:
    return n
else:
    return ( rec(n-1) + rec(n-2))

n=int(input())
```

Above code gets very slow in around 50th term.

Following code I have returned is also basically a recursion.

```
n=int(input())
n1,n2,count=0,1,0
def rec(n,n1,n2,count):
    if count<n:
        print(n1)
        nth=n1 + n2
        n1=n2
        n2=nth
        count+=1
        rec(n,n1,n2,count)
rec(n,n1,n2,count)
```

My question is are both of these approaches follow recursion (like the real recursion) ?

Comment: Whats *real recursion*?

Comment: like the first one.

Comment: Both are called *Recursive Functions*. And there's nothing like *Real Recursion*. The 1st function has two recursive calls and second one has one recursive call. What exactly  is your definition of *Real Recursion*? I never heard anything like that TBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they are both recursion, because you are calling the function `a()` inside itself. So, the main difference in both your functions is that there are two recursive calls on the first one and just one on the second one.

So now, on another matter:

> Above code gets very slow in around 50th term.

Well, you can do something interesting to do it faster. See, because of the recursive definition of Fibonacci sequence, you are doing the same calculations more than one.

For instance: imagine you are to compute `fibonacci(5)` so you need to compute `fibonacci(4)` and `fibonacci(3)`. But now, for `fibonacci(4)` you need to compute `fibonacci(3)` and `fibonacci(2)`, and so on. But wait, when you finish computing `fibonacci(4)` branch you already computed all fibonacci for 3 and 2, so when you go back to the other branch (`fibonacci(3)`) from the first recursive call, you already have computed it. So, What if there is a way I can store thos calculations so I can access them faster? You can do it with [Decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) to create a [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) class (some sort of memory to avoid repeated calculations):

This way we are going to store each computation of `fibonacci(k)` on a `dict` and we would check each time before a call if it exists on the dictionary, return if `True` or else compute it. This way is faster

```
class memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.f = function
        self.memory = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args in self.memory:
            return self.memory[args]
        else:
            value = self.f(*args)
            self.memory[args] = value
            return value

@memoize
def fib(n):
  if n <= 1:
    return n
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

r = fib(50)
print(r)
```

You can see that without [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) it took too long and with *memoization* it only took `0.263614`.

Hope this helps

Comment: One more question, why everyone including websites gives us the example of First code for teaching us recursion. because it is not efficient when we move to like 50+ terms. Second code is pretty much efficient.

Comment: @NikhilKaushal,  think because `Fibonacci` sequence is a classic mathematical recursive example easily understandable. However, maybe they could use it as a way to introduce this sort of techniques later in the website/book. Other recursive problem, but not so simple to grasp for a beginner are [Hanoi Towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi)

Answer (score 1):

Both functions are recursive, but as the last function has the call to itself as the last action in the function, it is also described as *tail recursive*.

Tail recursive function can easily be converted into loops:

```
def rec(n, n1=0, n2=1, count=0):
    while count < n:
        print(n1)
        n1, n2, count = n2, n1 + n2, count +1
```

Comment: first function also calls itself in the last action. Doesn't that make the first one also a tail recursive.

Comment: @NikhilKaushal, the last action does not mean the list line of code. You see on your last line of code `return  (rec(n-1) + rec(n-2))` there are two recursion calls, so the second one must wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: and after the calls have finished, their return values has to be added together.

Answer (score 0):

If a function calls itself, it is considered recursive.

The difference between your two implementations is that the first one calls itself approximately 2**n times, the second calls itself about n times.

For n = 50, 2**50 is 1125899906842624.  That's a lot of calls!  No wonder it takes a long time.  (Example: think of the number of times that `rec(10)` is called when calculating `rec(50)`.  Many, many, many times.)

While both of your functions are recursive, I'd say the latter is a "forward iteration", in that you are essentially moving FORWARD through the fibonacci sequence; for your second `rec(50)`, that function only recurses about 50 times.

One technique to make recursive calls faster is called **memoization**.   See ["Memoization" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  It works by immediately returning if the answer has previously been calculated... thereby not "re-recursing".

Comment: One more question, why everyone including websites gives us the example of First code for teaching us recursion. because it is not efficient when we move to like 50+ terms. Second code is pretty much efficient